# ModelForm.is_valid() is False when row already exists. How to get the object?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

My Location model has a unique filed called **name**. Through LocationForm I get user input and try to either insert it into the database or get the axisting object. But if user inputs an existing name, lf.is_valid() becomes False and I never get to the get_or_create command. Any idea how I can pass this?

```
lf = LocationForm(request.POST or None)
if lf.is_valid():
    location_instance, created = Location.objects.get_or_create(**lf.cleaned_data)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `ModelForm` then maybe you can try overriding `_get_validation_exclusions` method.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/8838d4dd498c8f66ea4237fe8a79a5f77d6f95c9/django/forms/models.py#L297

```
class LocationForm():
    def _get_validation_exclusions(self):
        exclude = super(LocationForm, self)._get_validation_exclusions()
        exclude.append(self.fields['name'])
        return exclude
```

Let me know how that goes..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your thought. 
I found a useful description of .is_valid in Django documentation. [Django Validating Objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects).
Apparently **.is_valid** also check against **Model.validate_unique()**.
Here is what I ended up doing:

```
if lf.is_valid():
     location_instance = lf.save()
     return render (...)

else:
    location_instance, created = Location.objects.get_or_create(**lf.cleaned_data)
    error_msg = lf.errors["__all__"]            
    return render(...)
```